# Single parameter argument with position equal to 1 or no argument value?

Tags: powershell, parameters

I have stumbled upon a function with single parameter, and there are 2 things I do not understand simply because documentation does not mention them.

Here is a function:

```
function Some-Function
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory,
        Position = 1, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string] $Input
    )
}
```

**Question 1:**

Since this is single parameter function, why is `Position` set to 1? what does that mean? I don't see any point here, what is wrong with the default value of `Position = 0`?

**Question 2:**

`ValueFromPipeline` and `Mandatory` arguments are not set to any value ie, `= $true` or `= $false`
what is the default value of these arguments if not set to value?

I can't find anywhere in the docs to explain this, and none of the examples on docs are like this one.

Comment: As an aside: Do _not_ use `$Input` as the name of a custom (parameter) variable: it is an _automatic variable_ that cannot be assigned to.

Comment: I've set this name while posting a question, didn't know it's automatic though, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since this is single parameter function, why is Position set to 1?

There is no strict need to set a `Position` property at all in this case.

- While it is a good *convention* to start `Position` properties with `0`, it isn't technically necessary - all that matters is the *relative* ordering of all parameters with `Position` attributes.
- In the *absence* of any `Position` properties, it is the order of *parameter declarations* (other than `[switch]` parameters) that *implicitly* defines their positional ordering, EXCEPT if you use `[CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding=$false)]`, in which case only *explicit* `Position` properties matter.

Note: The presence of `[CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding=$false)]` *or* at least one  `[Parameter(Position=...)]` attribute implicitly switch the default to *non-positional*: that is, all parameters that do not *explicitly* specify a `Position` value become *non-positional*, meaning they can only be passed arguments if preceded by the parameter's name (e.g., `-foo bar` instead of just `bar`).

---

> `ValueFromPipeline` and `Mandatory` arguments are not set to any value

In PowerShell **v3+**, omitting an attribute's property value defaults to `$true`, in the interest of brevity.

Comment: I agree but When i look at github powershell it says differently.
[System.Management.Automation/engine/Attributes](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/Attributes.cs) line 655

`/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets a flag that specifies that this parameter can take values from the incoming pipeline
/// object.
/// When it is not specified, false is assumed.
/// </summary>`
`public bool ValueFromPipeline { get; set; }`

Comment: @Arset, specifying something like `[Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]` _is_ specifying the property, only with an _implied value_ (supplied by the _PowerShell engine_), which is `$true`.